# how do i import my oracle database to oracle cloud website?

Tags: oracle

I want to import my oracle database from local server to oracle cloud Autonomous database , i have already exported dump file by using expdb and i need to import the database to oracle cloud , 
i created the database on the oracle cloud website , and i read details in the following link :

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/load-data-data-pump.html#GUID-30DB1EEA-DB45-49EA-9E97-DF49A9968E24

they wrote the steps after export :

Store your Cloud Object Storage credential using DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_CREDENTIAL. For example:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_CREDENTIAL(
    credential_name => 'DEF_CRED_NAME',
    username => 'adwc_user@example.com',
    password => 'password'
  );
END;
/
```

where i will execute this command in which platform or software , in command prompt or SQL developer , also after create credential import the database , where to import no full details in oracle website ?

There is another ways to import database to oracle cloud like golden gate SQL loader and SQL developer import wizard but this way data pump the recommended way by oracle and easiest one.

Also i have suggestion to admins to add new tag Oracle-Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the credential created in the db as shown, if you want, you can use SQL Developer (while connected to your Autonomous Database) use the Import Wizard to run your Data Pump Scenario.

View > DBA

Add your connection

Open Data Pump, right click on Import Jobs, and select the wizard

using the credential, pull up your DMP file in OSS

[image]

I share steps [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/01/data-pump-your-on-premises-oracle-database-to-the-autonomous-cloud/)

Comment: where i will execute this pl\sql block DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_CREDENTIAL in SQL developer also in autonomous database ?  , and the username and password will by my ADB same username and database password ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Abdullah in your oracle db, yes. It is the credentials for your Oracle Cloud Storage Service (OSS) - NOT your database credentials. It allows the database itself to GET or POST files back and forth.

Comment: Thank you so much , its helpful i will try it step by step .